# How can I get each EditText speech result of ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, speech-recognition

I have a ScrollView which has about 13 EditText. What I am trying to do is converting speech to text,so when the user touch any EditText and click speak button and start speaking, it will convert to text for that EditText,and when he again touch another EditText it will convert to text for that EditText with out changing the previous EditText and so on.. I used for loop but the result of one speech is found in all the 13 EditText. I also add a break statement but didn't work well.

```
 public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                //getting all the matches
                ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                        .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


                if (matches != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < speEdtId.length; j++) {
                        eEdit = findViewById(speEdtId[j]);

                        if (speEdtId[j]==speEdtId[0]) {
                            eEdit.setText(matches.get(0));
                        } else if (speEdtId[j]==speEdtId[1]) {
                            eEdit.setText(matches.get(0));
                        } else if (speEdtId[j]==speEdtId[2]) {
                            eEdit.setText(matches.get(0));}

                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
break;
                    }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same value to every Edittext. what you can do is:

```
                              if (speEdtId[j]==speEdtId[0]) {
                                eEdit.setText(matches.get(0));
                                matches.clear();
                            }
```

And also set tag to every Edittext and find with tag within the loop. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will have a lot of Speech EditText, I am not sure how you want your program to work with EditText so I will use TextView instead in my solution. In my opinion, it would be better and more efficient to use RecyclerViews than manually creating 13 EditText.

First I will create a Speech object. You can add as many variables you want like for example Timestamp of the speech

Speech.java

```
public class Speech {
    private String speechInText;
    private String speech;

    public Speech(){

    }

    public Speech(String speechInText, String speech) {
        this.speechInText = speechInText;
        this.speech = speech;
    }

    public String getSpeechInText() {
        return speechInText;
    }

    public void setSpeechInText(String speechInText) {
        this.speechInText = speechInText;
    }

    public String getSpeech() {
        return speech;
    }

    public void setSpeech(String speech) {
        this.speech = speech;
    }

}
```

Then, I would create an adapter to each of the speeches

SpeechAdapter.java

```
public class SpeechAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SpeechAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    public static final String TAG = SpeechAdapter.class.getName();

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Speech speech, int pos);
    }

    private List<Speech> speeches;
    private AppCompatActivity parentActivity;
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public SpeechAdapter(AppCompatActivity parentActivity, List<Speech> speeches, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        this.speeches = speeches;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView speechInTextTV;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            parentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    speechInTextTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.speechInTextTV);
                }
            });
        }

        public void bind(final Speech speech,final int pos, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(speech, pos);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_speech_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int pos) {
        final Speech speech = speeches.get(pos);
        holder.speechInTextTV.setText(speech.getSpeechInText());

        holder.bind(speech, pos, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return speeches.size();
    }
}
```

Next, I will create an XML file for the adapter

adapter_speech_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speechInTextTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, the Activity file or Fragment file

SpeechActivity.java

```
public class SpeechActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static final String TAG = SpeechActivity.class.getName();

    private SpeechAdapter speechAdapter;
    private List<Speech> speeches = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView speechRV;
    private int selectedSpeechPosition;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

        speechRV = findViewById(R.id.speechRV);

        //I add 13 text views manually here (with empty data)
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
            speeches.add(new Speech("",""));
        }

        speechAdapter = new SpeechAdapter(this, speeches, new SpeechAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Speech speech, int position) {
                /*
                    you convert speech to text here
                 */
                selectedSpeechPosition = position;
            }
        });

        speechRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        speechRV.setAdapter(speechAdapter);
        speechRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
        //getting all the matches
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        /*here you get the result of the converted speech and update the speeches list and then update the adapter to refresh the view*/
        String convertedSpeech = "<PUT_YOUR_RESULT_HERE>";
        speeches.set(selectedSpeechPosition,new Speech(convertedSpeech,"user's original speech or something else?"));
        speechAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and finally the xml file for the activity

activity_speech.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/speechRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This solution is only an example and my way of doing it if I am in your spot. You should study the code and manipulate it yourself to fulfill your own requirement.

Basically, you should pass in some kind of data into the speeches List and update the adapter in the onResult function and the recycler view will be refreshed with new data. When I am initializing the adapter in the activity file, I have implemented a OnItemClick function so when the user clicks on an item in the recycler view it will save the selected speech's position so that it in the onResult function, you can know which speech you should update (by using the selectedSpeechPosition)